# What the statement 'cold state' means?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

If someone is able to explain to me what the statement means cold state in relation to databases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caches empty, no table data or indexes preloaded into memory, *etc*. Basically, database in a state as if you'd just started it (and the machine) up.